# How to kill single-particle Quantum Mechanics(complex integration help)

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, polar-coordinates

I was reading the part of QuantumFieldTheory where you check if a particle could exist at **x**=0 to **x**=x in space-like plane of a light-cone, therefore if non-zero result, quantum mechanics becomes incompatible with general relativity.But I could not understand the complex integration. The whole problem is below, I had to upload the screenshot, as I do not know how to use this message box to write equations:

[image]

I hope I had provided enough information about the question,(by now I've learnt how to use the math_editor :) ) what I'd like to know is, how did the $e^{i|x||p|}$ of the third to the last line has become $e^{-m|x|} \int_{m}^\infty dzz e^{-(z-m)}$ in the last line,
and $e^{-it {\sqrt |p|^2 - m^2}}$ of the same, third to the last line, has become $sinh(t{\sqrt z^2 - m^2 })$ in the last line. This is what I meant in my original question, when I said how did the integral developed, especially the parts that mapped on the contour.

appreciated for help and apologised for any mistake both in advance
kind regards

***I have editted the picture and corrected the typos, there is absolutely no mistake in the question, at least no mistake in my part, as I've copied the page of the book correctly. For those who might own the book; Quantum Field Theory for the gifted amateur by Tom Lancaster and Stephen J. Blundell, page75, equation 8.18 and page 76, eqt. 8.19 with Figure 8.3***

Note: If someone can embed the image again, instead of a plain link, I'd appreciate

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thank you, but for now,I'm going to wait until someone tells me(if what i did is against the forum rules) to write it specifically with the text editor, as I've already provided a readable version of the question(as an image) and its killing me to write it once more.I'm going to try my chance

Comment: MathJax is easier to read than your image.

Comment: There is no conversion of complex variables to polar coordinates. Have you ever used Jacobians?

Comment: I don't understand the substitution from the third to last to second to last line. It's not $p=\pm iz$. There are a lot of typos and perhaps outright errors, too, so overall, I'm skeptical of this work.

Comment: did you, @zahbaz, editted my question and asked what I've asked by only using sentences? because that is exactly what I've asked in my last edit, only with equations, but apparently someone deleted that? why? and by the way, there is no typo other thatn the extra d next to the integral from 0 to infinity, in the operator A's description. I have written this question exactly as it was printed in the book, and this is why im asking it.

Comment: @bergdi The content of your question is the same as it has been, the only edit I made was to display the image instead of a link to the image. Also, I deleted my own answer, because it wasn't addressing what you were looking for. Third. by typos, I mean that I think the math in the image may be incorrect! At least, it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: ah, ok, now i see...you see, by deleting your answer, you also deleted my comment to your answer which was the last version of my question :D I worked too hard to wrote that, never mind, let me write it again

Comment: Aha, that's one of the lesser-known dangers of writing essential information that should have been in the question, but putting it in a comment instead.

Comment: So, I've corrected my wording and made my question as clear as possible, but it's still on hold. Even thou it's been editted by one of the admins, right after I finished my correcting. What else should I have to do to make it 'on hold' no more?

Comment: Helloooo?! why is it still on hold days after I have corrected the wording as requested?